# Can I capture a POST request when navigating a page via RSelenium, or the embedded javascript output?

Tags: r, selenium, rvest, httr, rselenium

I'm interacting with a website running a Javascript that dynamically produces the page through a series of button clicks. Here is an example from a different website:
[Bridgerton buzzfeed quiz](https://www.buzzfeed.com/bridgertongirls/only-true-fan-can-match-these-quotes-to-the-correc-aeyl4amas9)

Each button click produces a change on the webpage, and ultimately gives you a score at the end once you've clicked through all of them. I'm interested in the POST request produced by the final button click on the page. Any of the following would do as a solution for what I need:

- capture the change in the website when the button is pushed (for this example, the score box at the end that comes up now says "3 out of 10" or something of the like)
- catch the output of the POST request (the score that is being put into the webpage)
- get the POST request so I can resubmit it to capture the response

I have successfully reproduced the POST request from the website I'm looking at using httr and browser web developer tools, but it's session-specific (cookies etc.) so I then went the route of using RSelenium. From several answers, it looks like this is something Selenium can't handle (unless those are now outdated). However, I see there's a python package (selenium-wire) that seems to do exactly this. Are there any equivalent tools for R? I was also looking at splashr/HARtools but I'm not quite sure how to piece this into my workflow.

Comment: If you just need session cookies, then you can use `rvest` instead of `RSelenium`. Doing that, you may be able to extract or mimic the POST request given the arguments you feed to `rvest::submit_form`.

Comment: Why did you tag [tag:python] and [tag:javascript]? If you're looking for solutions in those languages, I suggest you explicitly say that in your question; if you're including javascript because the page uses it, that's not correct, you don't have a question about programming in javascript. I suggest you remove [tag:javascript] and [tag:python], and add [tag:rselenium] if you need to stick with that package. If you want to consider `rvest`, you can try removing [tag:selenium] and adding [tag:rvest]. Just some thoughts.

Comment: BrowserMob proxy?

Comment: Can we please have an [mcve] in line with [ask].